# Canvas Units to Degrees, Minutes, Seconds

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wgs84, degrees-minutes-seconds

I am using the WGS 84/UTM coordinate sysytem.

When I go to > Project Properties / General / Canvas Units to Degrees, Minutes, Seconds my coordinates are wrong.

I am using QGIS 2.0.1

[image]

Comment: Save this as separate shapefile defining the same projection and try once again.

Answer (score 3):

UTM always has metres as units.

If you want degrees, change the project CRS to EPSG:4326 (WGS84) first. Then you can switch from decimal degrees to degrees-minutes-seconds as you did.

Comment: EPSG:4326 is a Geographic Coordinate System and EPSG:32635 (WGS 84/UTM zone 35N) is a Projected Coordinate System. When i set CRS to EPSG:4326 my data is distorted. How come ArcMap is able to display DMS in Projected Coordinate Systems ?

Comment: You are right, EPSG:4326 looks distorted, because 1 degree East is not the same as 1 degree North, the more you are away from the aequator. The coordinate status bar of Arcmap works differently: The map is displayed projected, but the coordinate status bar is reprojected to EPSG:4326 degrees, if you want that.

Comment: Ok. Show is there a way to display correct DMS for projected coordinate systems in QGIS ? My real problem is that I want to be able in Print Composer - Show Grid - Draw Coordinates to show DMS correctly. This only works if I set CRS to Geographic but data in the map is distorted.

Comment: You can add another layer just with a degrees grid in EPSG:4326: `Vector -> Research Tools -> Vector Raster`. Make sure to densify the lines if they should appear curved in the projection you use.